# How to force date from a form into a specific timezone in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, timezone

When getting the date from a textfield like: "20-11 15:43" is it possible to force it into a specific timezone without too much parsing?

`DateTime.strptime("20-11 15:43",'%d-%m %H:%M')` gives me `Tue, 20 Nov 2012 15:43:00 +0000`
 instead of `Tue, 20 Nov 2012 15:43:00 +0100`

Right now I use `DateTime.strptime(date_from_textfield+" +0100",'%d-%m %H:%M %Z')` which seems to be alright, but id rather not append `+0100` to my value. Is there a way to get DateTime to use the `config.time_zone = 'Amsterdam'` I set in my `application.rb`?